# I am trying to implement custom directive to clear button in a inputfield

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get data from coponent to directive. How I do it using ComponentFactory and ComponentRef.

This is my input field code:

```html
<input type="text" class="standard-text-field" appClearInput>
```

Then this is my directive :

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appClearInput]'
})

export class QmClearInputDirective implements OnInit{
  Ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(ClearButtonComponent);
 constructor(private el: ElementRef, public viewContainerRef:      ViewContainerRef) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {}
  
  @HostListener('input',['$event'])
  onInput(event: any) {
    if(!event){console.log('no');}
    else{
      this.updateButtonVisibility(event.target.value);
    }

  }

  updateButtonVisibility(inputText: string) {
    if (inputText) {
      console.log('inputText is',inputText);
      this.Ref.instance.isVisible = true;
    } else {
      this.Ref.instance.isVisible = false;
    }
  }
}
```

The my close button component file

Html and .ts codes are here:

```js
export class ClearButtonComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input()
  isVisible: Boolean = false;

  @Output() clear = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  buttonClicked($event:any) {
    console.log('clear', $event);
    this.clear.emit();
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
  }

}
```

```html
<span *ngIf="isVisible" class="input-button">
  <span (click)="buttonClicked($event)">clear
  </span>
</span>
```

So in this case clear button is appear in inputfield when type something and I need to create event when click the close button and through this event access directive and clear the input field and hide the close button.

Comment: A directive to reset a input. That is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First the parents *HTML*

**HTML Parent**

```
<div class="input">
  <input
    clearInput
    [clearInput]="value"
    #inputVal
    type="text"
    placeholder="Clearable input"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
  />
  <div class="alwaysCloseButtonWillBethere">Close</div>
</div>
```

Parents Code part is very small:

**Code Parent**

```
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  value = '';
}
```

Now the interesting part. The `Directive`:

**Directive Part**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clearInput]',
  exportAs: 'clearInput',
  standalone: true
})
export class ClearInputDirective implements OnChanges , OnInit , OnDestroy{
   
    @Input('clearInput') inputValue: any;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2 , private model: NgModel) {
      
  }

  ngOnInit(){
     this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.children[1].addEventListener('click', () =>{
       this.model.control.reset();
     })
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
   if(changes.inputValue){
      if(this.inputValue){
       this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.children[1], 'display', 'block');
       }
       else {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.children[1], 'display', 'none');
       }
   }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
     this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.children[1].removeEventListener('click',null
     );
  }
}
```

How it works? Inside parents html we add an input and a button. The button's class has nothing to do with the functionality.
The directive use the value to get the `ngModel`. Then the directive searching the second element inside its parents div. So the button in our case. And only when any input is given, the directive will be shown the button.

You can make it better with a extra directive for the button to identify, or let `Renderer2` create a button dynamically. But the way to go is this.

A Stackblitz example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6rhaa?file=src/app.component.html).

Comment: I need to use this close button in multiple input fields. Then I can call this component through directive.

Comment: You can reuse it... each input can have this directive.